# Toggle is not clossing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this toggle which is working fine.
I just want to close one when second is clicked.

Right now its opening all the slides.

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("h3.symple-toggle-trigger").click(function() { 
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast"); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can't you format and indent your code so we can _read_ it?

Comment: Also seeing your HTML would help.

Comment: I guess: `$("h3.symple-toggle-trigger.active").not(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp('fast');` at top of click handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/qfvy2wnb/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your html is structured exactly but I put together an example of html that will work with a few alterations to your JavaScript. You may have to tinker around with it to get the exact desired effect your looking for but I believe it is pretty close.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/yeoGNr

HTML:

```
<h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">
  Trigger 1
</h3>
<p  class="section">
  section 1
</p>
<h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">
  Trigger 2
</h3>
<p  class="section">
  section 2
</p>
<h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">
  Trigger 3
</h3>
<p  class="section">
  section 3
</p>
```

I removed the document ready function call from your code. You will not need it if you are loading your scripts before the closing `</body>` tag. If you are loading your script from the `<head>` element then you will need to add it back.
I rearranged your anonymous function wrap/closure so that it returns the jQuery object just in case you want to use another library with your code in the future. I don't know if that matters to you are not I just thought it might help.

JavaScript:

```
(function($){//begin closure


        $("h3.symple-toggle-trigger").click(function() { 

  var active = $(this).index(".symple-toggle-trigger");

          $(this).next(".section").slideToggle("fast");

   $(".symple-toggle-trigger").each(function(i){//begin each


    //if the element index doesn't equal the active index or the element clicked on.
    if(i !== active){//begin if then

   //hide the section
   $(".section")[i].style.display = "none";

    }//end if then

   });//end each

        }); 

}(jQuery));//end closure
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li div{ display: none;}
li div.open{ display: block;}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".symple-toggle-trigger").click(function(){
        $("ul li div").slideUp();
        $("ul li h3.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active").next().slideDown();
    });
});

<ul>
    <li>
        <h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">Heading 01</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">Heading 01</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">Heading 01</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">Heading 01</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="symple-toggle-trigger">Heading 01</h3>
        <div>Content</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Click here for Demo https://jsfiddle.net/pixeldew/u5qg21fx/